# React NextAuth credentials null and Auth Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, next-auth

1. I get the following error:

[image: Error]

here is my code:

```
return (
    <>
      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => {
        if (provider.id === "credentials") {
          return null;
        }

        return (
          <div key={provider.name}>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={() => {
                setAppLoading(true);
                signIn(provider.id);
                setAppLoading(false);
              }}
              className="w-full uppercase !transform-none mt-4"
            >
              <Image
                height={24}
                width={24}
                src={`/logos/${provider.name}.svg` || "/logos/google.svg"}
                alt={provider.name}
              />
              <span className="ml-2 !text-[rgba(26, 26, 44, 0.5)]">
                Sign in with {provider.name}
              </span>
            </Button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

If I silence the error by adding { providers !=== null && ... }, the page loads however,
the auth does not work at all, almost as if it is not getting fired

Here is the Form Button onSubmit, which gets called when I click it however, the signIn("credentials...}) doesn't fire

```
import { ClientSafeProvider, signIn } from "next-auth/client";

...

 onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors }) => {
          const { email, password } = values;

          setAppLoading(true);
          signIn("credentials", {
            email,
            password,
            redirect: false,
          }).then((res) => {
            setErrors({ error: res?.error });
          });

          setAppLoading(false);
        }}
...
```

and lastly, here is my [...nextauth].ts

```
import login from "features/auth/login";
import register from "features/auth/register";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        name: { label: "Name", type: "text" },
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },

      async authorize(credentials, _req) {
        const { name, email, password } = credentials;
        alert("clicked");
        console.log("CLICKEEEED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        if (typeof name === "undefined") {
          return login(email, password);
        }
        return register(name, email, password);
      },
    }),
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
    error: "/auth/error", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // (used for check email message)
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you have provided valid `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` and `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` in your `.env.local` file? This is the most common cause of your error. This would mean that `next-auth` did not provide you with `providers`, because of an error in the api.